# How to grant public read access to an S3 object using SignedURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm using [SignedURL](https://pkg.go.dev/gocloud.dev/blob#Bucket.SignedURL) method to generate an URL that can be used by the end user to upload a document. I would like to make that document(after it's uploaded) public by default but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward option. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you use a [POST signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) that supports a policy with `"acl": "public-read"` (example [here](https://www.matano.dev/blog-archive/2022/02/14/s3-post-policy)), or trigger a Lambda function after upload to S3 to apply the public-read ACL?

Comment: The Go SDK doesn't seem to support a POST signed URL (am I wrong?). I thought about Lambda but it just feels like an unnecessary burden for something as simple as a configuration.

Comment: Agree, it doesn't look like the Go SDK exposes a method for creating a signed POST. I suppose you could always just write a small Lambda function in [Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_presigned_post.html) or [Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html). Or go the S3 event triggered Lambda route.

Comment: For reference, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1224) to implement this in the underlying SDK, though it's been open for a while.